# Django database error while making field unique

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

On User table i changed phone field to unique by adding `unique=True` .

when i run `makemigrations` it created file like this :

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('User', '0005_auto_20200321_1543'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='phone',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=13, unique=True, verbose_name='phone'),
        ),
    ]
```

after running `migrate` command it raises this error :

> psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation
>   "User_user_phone_5262bb8b_like" already exists

I checked postgres database constraints and tables . there is no table or relation with this name . so i think there is a problem in migration files .
how can i solve this ?

In Past `phone` field was unique and i changed it . now again I change it to unique .

Comment: Seems that you have two identical phone entries. You should make sure that the entries are unique before trying to migrate to unique

Comment: Run `showmigrations` to see the list of pending migrations to be applied - make sure that this is the very migration causing the issue.